# Count nodes with more than 3 neighbours in distributed computing, initiating by one site

Tags: algorithms, graphs, distributed-systems

I have an algorithm that visit all the nodes on a graph in distributed computing , the initiator is one site only , I want to change it so that the initiator can in the end of the execution know the nodes that have more than 3 neighbours ,
So the initiator is one site and the result expected is the list of the nodes that  have more than 3 nodes

Comment: The title states `initiating by all sites`, the question body ends `the initiator is one site`. `I have an algorithm` If you want it discussed, better present it. If it is the work of somebody else, properly attribute it - hyperlink welcome for reference&details.

Comment: @greybeard I was wanting to say intiated by one Site, so I was working on an algorithm for Counting by initiating from all sites and by one site , I am not an expert in distributed algorithm I am new in this domain